# "На основании документа" - это как понимать?

Tags: значение-слов

На основании документа. "Документа" - Родительный падеж имеет две стороны. Пример со стулом, который стоит на полу. Пол - основание для стула, а сам стул служит основанием, когда на стуле кто-либо сидит или стоит. Стало быть, "на основании стула" - это либо пол, либо сам стул. Но если сам стул, то точнее говорить "стул - основание", а не "на основании стула". 
Так и с документом. Что же имеется в виду под "основанием" документа, если их два?

(Не путайте "основание" с "основой", то есть содержание документа - это не основание, а основа)
(Этот вопрос касается вопроса: "согласно документА/У).

Comment: Похоже, вы сами запутались в вашем вопросе. Поскольку ваш вопрос не имеет никакого сиысла, если понимать его так, как вы. Вам дали аргументированный ответ. А вы троллите.

Answer (score 0):

> **“На основании документа” - это как понимать?**

Очень простой вопрос. Открываем толковый словарь Кузнецова и смотрим первые три из приведенных там семи значений.

> **ОСНОВАНИЕ**, -я; ср. **1.** к Основать. О. города, государства. Год
>   основания столицы. Столетие со дня основания театра. **2.** Нижняя опорная
>   часть предмета, сооружения. Заложить, укрепить о. Каменное, кирпичное
>   о. Естественное о. О. моста, колонны, мачты, горы. Площадь основания.
>   Памятник на гранитном основании. **3.** То, на чём строится, зиждется,
>   создаётся что-л.; источник; основа (2 зн.). О. какой-л. классификации.
>   О. политической системы. В основании картинной галереи лежит частная
>   коллекция. Основанием для поэмы послужили народные предания.

В данном случае нас интересует не второе значение, которое не совсем правильно понимает (или формулирует) автор вопроса, а третье. Путать это слово со словом **основа** не нужно, но понимать, что в данном значении оно практически синонимично соответствующему значению "основы" не повредит.

Comment: "Основа" и "основание" - разные понятия. Если продолжить пример со стулом, то основой стула являются его деревянные части (а если перевести на "документ", то основа документа - содержание). Речь об "основании", оно может иметь две стороны. Об этом вопрос. Одна сторона, видимо, что-то сторонее, вторая сторона - это что-то от нас документу.

Comment: Если Вы получили чёткий, понятный и аргументированный ответ на свой вопрос, просто поставьте галочку возле ответа. Здесь так принято. Длительные дискуссии этой площадке запрещены правилами, здесь принят формат "вопрос — ответ". В некоторых случаях модераторы могут закрывать глаза на нарушения (особенно в случае интересных и содержательных обсуждений), но я просил бы не провоцировать.

Comment: Вы не поняли, что в вопросе. Я выясняю что служит документу основанием, их два: 1) что-то стороннее - законы или правила?; 2) что-то от нас? Что это может быть для документа? Не надо мне словарей, давно бы уж поняли, что не пользуюсь я ими.

Comment: У меня нет никаких сомнений, что я правильно понял вопрос. Если Вы хотите его изменить, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "правка". И учитесь пользоваться словарями — при определённом навыке это не так уж сложно. Иначе очень сложно общаться при такой значительной разнице в уровнях подготовки.

Answer (score 0):

**Нет** такой сущности как "*основание документа*".

> Ничто не *происходит* без достаточного **основания** (Лебниц).
>
> http://intencia.ru/Pages-view-349.html

В нашем случае *логическим **основанием** для принятия кем-то решений  или совершения действий* является документ определённого содержания. Формально подразумевают "**на основании изложенного в документе**" (*факт наличия* документа определённого содержания, в условиях уместности или обязательности им руководствоваться), но в порядке речевого упрощения называют (в качестве причины, основания для своих действий) сам *документ*.

Comment: Нет. Вы ещё одну сущность делаете - "основание изложенного в документе", плюс к тому, что есть просто "основание документа". Я копаю вопрос "согласно документА/У", и Дательный падеж - это как раз то, что мы даем документу, чтобы он был основанием. А есть ещё основание, где документ опирается на что-то стороннее - это уже, видимо, не Дательный падеж (не уверен). "Основа" же  документа полностью за Родительным падежом.

Comment: _Основание_ не является принадлежностью документа, это основание, на котором действуют люди. Таким основанием является факт наличия документа с некоторым содержанием + обязанность или желание на этом содержании основываться. "Согласно чему" лучше посмотреть в старых ответах - во избежание новых недоразумений.

Comment: Дать силу, ход документу - это идет от людей. И это Дательный падеж. Но если затрагивается содержание документа, то это - Родительный падеж.

Comment: Если упростить:_Он был уволен на основании приказа._ У самого "приказа" здесь нет "основания". Приказ **сам** был _основанием для увольнения_. Смысл не одними только падежами определяется, имеет значение сочетаемость понятий и т. п.

Comment: Вот, это как раз и есть в примере со стулом - пол. Пример с приказом удачный. Основание приказа: либо нарушение, либо решение начальства - не сам приказ.

Comment: Основание _как причина_ (по упомянутому Лейбницу; аналогия с геометрией здесь непродуктивна) есть у _всех_ событий (как и у факта существования чего-либо). Нарушение - основание для (издания) приказа об увольнении, приказ - основание для увольнения (сотрудниками отдела кадров) и т. д.

Comment: Если приказ - основание, то только тогда, когда кто-то признает его таковым (даёт ему законную силу). От геометрии не ушли: нарушение (причина) - пол для стула; признание - стул, на котором сидят или стоят.